# iPhone 7 battery quickly discharges after using Philips dual USB car charger

Tags: iphone, battery, charging

I drove a car for about 3 hours and during the ride my iPhone 7 was connected to the [Philips dual USB car charger](https://www.philips.com.sg/c-p/DLP2259_10/dual-usb-car-charger). All this time screen was on and also was using Waze app. In addition to this another phone was charging during the ride.

After this trip I noticed that my phone discharges very fast every time I charge it in classic way from home. Does it mean that my battery could been damaged because of the ride? Is there any options to solve this problem? The phone is year and a half old.

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend using M-Fi certified chargers and certified usb wall blocks! These are crucial for the health of your iPhone’s battery! Your battery may not have been charged well with that kind of chord and wall/car socket! I suggest buying a certified car kit! They sell them on amazon for like $20 max